# onClick event on a SlidingDrawer not triggered

Tags: android, onclick, slidingdrawer

I created a RelativeLayout containing an ImageView and a SlidingDrawer. I set an onClickListener on the ImageView and another one on the content part of the SlidingDrawer. When the SlidingDrawer is open and I click on its content part, the onClick event of the ImageView is triggered.

Why? Isn't the SlidingDrawer above the ImageView?

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/whip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />  

    <SlidingDrawer
         android:id="@+id/drawer"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="53dp"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:orientation="horizontal"

         android:handle="@+id/facebook_icon"
         android:content="@+id/facebook_contacts">

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/facebook_icon"
             android:layout_width="55dp"
             android:layout_height="53dp"         
             android:src="@drawable/facebook_handler_off" />

         <ImageView android:id="@+id/facebook_contacts"
                android:layout_width="265dp"
                android:layout_height="53dp"                
                android:src="@drawable/facebook_content" /> 

    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hey did you ever found out solution for this? I am facing the same problem and none of the solutions are helping me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to intercept the mouse evensts with the implementation of
boolean  onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)

Giving to the doc, this method "intercept all touch screen motion events".

You return true if you want to treat the specific MotionEvent (giving in parameters) with the SlidingDrawer.

Look the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` too :)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)